# Deleting from android sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a column in android sqlite database table. The values in the column are like:

```
2011/06/01
2011/06/02
2011/06/05
2011/06/10
2011/06/11
2011/06/13
2011/06/15
2011/06/16
2011/06/25
2011/06/26
```

I have a string `today="2011/06/27"`

Now I want to delete those rows whose column value is older than 5 days from today.

How to modify the code to achieve this?

```
return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE,where date="", null) > 0;
```

Comment: Use a date column in your SQL not String

Comment: @Blundell that should be the answer, not a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to store your dates in a other format, check [the date function of SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Use `YYYY-MM-DD` instead of `YYYY/MM/DD`. You already got an order on your dates defined by its string representation. So you can use the date function of SQLite to select the correct rows.

Dates older than 5 days would be queried like this.

```
... WHERE datecolumn < date('now', '-5 days') ...
```

Comment: is my date column not considered as date

Comment: Add your create table statement so we can see who you create your table.

Comment: private static final String USAGE_TABLE = "create table batteryUsage (id integer primary key autoincrement,"
   + "date date not null,time text not null,level integer)";

Answer (score 0):

There is no date type in sqllite

you just store a data represented value as a string or int

then use the date based functions of sqllite to get the values

Answer (score -1):

You should be using the stored procedure rather than writing the service. It will make easier for your application to automatically update the records.

See link: http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/Time-based-stored-procedure-to-check-table-and-update-old-records

Another solution is to use date instead of string. When you run your service then fetch data as Date and then you can make the simple comparison.

Comment: SQLite doesn't provide stored procedures.

Comment: However, I checked further that SQLite doesn't provide time-based stored procedure.